# When using slick slider and have slide with row which have 2 divs it becomes column with 2 divs. Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, flexbox, bootstrap-4, slick.js

I need to make slider which have slide with row which have 2 divs in it. But when I try to use slick slider this row becomes column. Using Bootstrap 4 and flexbox.

My HTML:

```
<section class="main-slider">
    <div class="container-fluid sl">
        <div class="row slider-content justify-content-center align-items-lg-center">
            <div class="left-side d-flex flex-column col-11 col-sm-7 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                <h1 class="main-slider-header top-header">We Believe</h1>
                <h1 class="main-slider-header bottom-header">in quality design</h1>
                <p class="slider-text top-text">Any creative project is unique</p>
                <p class="slider-text middle-text">and should be provided with</p>
                <p class="slider-text bottom-text">the appropriate quality</p>
                <a class="btn slider-btn" href="#">Order Now</a>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side text-center col-lg-8 col-xl-6">
                <ul class="row people-list justify-content-center">
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-1.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-2.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-3.png"></li>
                    <li class="offset-lg-3 offset-xl-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-4.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-5.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-6.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-7.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-8.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-9.png"></li>
                    <li class="col-xl-12"><img class="img-fluid " src="images/main-slider-img-10.png"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row slider-content justify-content-center align-items-lg-center">
            <div class="right-side text-center col-lg-8 col-xl-6">
                <ul class="row people-list justify-content-center">
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-1.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-2.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-3.png"></li>
                    <li class="offset-lg-3 offset-xl-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-4.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-5.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-6.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-7.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-8.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-9.png"></li>
                    <li class="col-xl-12"><img class="img-fluid " src="images/main-slider-img-10.png"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="left-side d-flex flex-column col-11 col-sm-7 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                <h1 class="main-slider-header top-header">We Believe</h1>
                <h1 class="main-slider-header bottom-header">in quality design</h1>
                <p class="slider-text top-text">Any creative project is unique</p>
                <p class="slider-text middle-text">and should be provided with</p>
                <p class="slider-text bottom-text">the appropriate quality</p>
                <a class="btn slider-btn" href="#">Order Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row slider-content justify-content-center align-items-lg-center">
            <div class="left-side d-flex flex-column col-11 col-sm-7 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                <h1 class="main-slider-header top-header">We Believe</h1>
                <h1 class="main-slider-header bottom-header">in quality design</h1>
                <p class="slider-text top-text">Any creative project is unique</p>
                <p class="slider-text middle-text">and should be provided with</p>
                <p class="slider-text bottom-text">the appropriate quality</p>
                <a class="btn slider-btn" href="#">Order Now</a>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side text-center col-lg-8 col-xl-6">
                <ul class="row people-list justify-content-center">
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-1.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-2.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-3.png"></li>
                    <li class="offset-lg-3 offset-xl-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-4.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-5.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-6.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-7.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-8.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-9.png"></li>
                    <li class="col-xl-12"><img class="img-fluid " src="images/main-slider-img-10.png"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row slider-content justify-content-center align-items-lg-center">
            <div class="right-side text-center col-lg-8 col-xl-6">
                <ul class="row people-list justify-content-center">
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-1.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-2.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-3.png"></li>
                    <li class="offset-lg-3 offset-xl-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-4.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-5.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-6.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-7.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-8.png"></li>
                    <li><img class="img-fluid" src="images/main-slider-img-9.png"></li>
                    <li class="col-xl-12"><img class="img-fluid " src="images/main-slider-img-10.png"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="left-side d-flex flex-column col-11 col-sm-7 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                <h1 class="main-slider-header top-header">We Believe</h1>
                <h1 class="main-slider-header bottom-header">in quality design</h1>
                <p class="slider-text top-text">Any creative project is unique</p>
                <p class="slider-text middle-text">and should be provided with</p>
                <p class="slider-text bottom-text">the appropriate quality</p>
                <a class="btn slider-btn" href="#">Order Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here how it looks without slick slider (correct):
[image]

Here how it looks with slick slider initialized (need to look like on the first screenshot): 
[image]

Initializing slick slider:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sl').slick({
});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Slick carousel enforces some styles on the tags that has the `.slider-content` class, and in the meantime you are using these very same nodes as the Bootstrap `.row`s. In order to solve this, you should use separate tags in your markup for these two separate functionalities.

So basically you could have your markup outlined as below.

```
<section class="main-slider">
    <div class="container-fluid sl">
        <!-- Note that `.slider-content` wraps `.row` -->
        <div class="slider-content">
            <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-lg-center">
                <div class="left-side d-flex flex-column col-11 col-sm-7 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                    <!-- Text -->
                </div>
                <div class="right-side text-center col-lg-8 col-xl-6">
                    <!-- Images of people -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- …Other slides… -->
    </div>
</section>
```